# Why does this div element not extend to the top of the screen?

Tags: css, html, reveal.js

Given the following bit of css

```
.reveal .fulldiv{
    position:fixed;
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

With a simple html file `<div class="fulldiv">foo</div>` I get what I expect, a green background with foo in the upper left. When I'm using [`reveal.js`](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js) to create an HTML5 presentation, I get instead:

[image]

I thought that using `position:fixed` wouldn't care about anything that it is wrapped up in. However it seems respect some container that it is in. **How can I get this div to extend the full screen as before?**

For completeness, here is the body (without the script calls) used for the picture:

```
<div class="reveal"><div class="slides">
<section class="vertical-stack">
  <section class="vertical-slide">
    <div class="fulldiv">foo</div>
  </section>
</section>
</div></div>
```

Comment: if you want width and height 100% of the actual screen , not the parent , then why can't you change the HTML so that it doesn't have a parent? or make position: absolute

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/R9Hzg Must be something else at play.

Comment: `position:absolute` has no effect (tried that as well). The slides are being auto-generated so I would rather not edit the html outside this container.

Comment: @isherwood I agree, I must be something that is done in the css or js of `reveal.js`. What can hold a div to a container when using absolute or fixed positioning?

Comment: An iframe. I don't see one in your image, though.

Comment: @jonasnas To the extent of my knowledge, I didn't see any of that. My screenshot was intended to show that the `position:fixed` is not overridden by the time the browser is done. As for a js override, I have _no idea_ how to check for that.

Comment: did you try to set all top, bottom, right, left to 0 to see if it takes any effect? P.S. Yes I saw only after my comment that you provided the developer tools screen as well.

Comment: @jonasnas I set what was listed in the css in the question. This works for the simple html. Wouldn't setting right/left and top/bottom to zero be ambiguous?

Comment: Why do you think it would be ambiguous? It sets the margin edge for a positioned box. So If I set all for 5px its like full screen with 5px margin

Comment: @jonasnas Setting top/bottom and left/right doesn't do anything. The element is still bound to something that I can't see.

Comment: If I were you I would start going up the dom and removing all classes/styles from parent divs(in developer tools) until proper rendering of your fixed element happens. Then try to see what exactly clashes with your element. Or modify html itself in developer tools to unwrap div by div

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43157/discussion-between-hooked-and-jonasnas)

Answer (score 0):

Your missing a comma in the css

```
.reveal, .fulldiv{
position:fixed;
background: green;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
```